# Yarn - Error: Error retrieving binary: Not Found - Solidity project

Tags: node.js, ethereum, yarnpkg, solidity

So I'm trying to understand how testing works with solidity contracts. So I cloned Uniswapv2's Core repo locally, installed all yarn dependencies and tried running 'yarn compile' as it states in their README.

This is what happens when I do so:

```
PS C:\Users\Laptop\crypto\uniswap_test\uniswap-v2-core> yarn compile
Error: Error retrieving binary: Not Found
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Laptop\crypto\uniswap_test\uniswap-v2-core\.yarn\cache\solc-npm-0.6.6-caef95cd78-47111f86f8.zip\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:334:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:636:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:129:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:502:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:227:10)
```

After that I installed Waffle with `yarn add waffle` which then produced the following when compiling:

```
PS C:\Users\Laptop\crypto\uniswap_test\uniswap-v2-core> yarn compile
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Laptop\crypto\uniswap_test\uniswap-v2-core\cache\solcjs\node_modules\solc.js'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Laptop\\crypto\\uniswap_test\\uniswap-v2-core\\cache\\solcjs\\node_modules\\solc.js'
}
```

But there's nothing inside that folder as can be seen in the attached screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have any clue on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your solc version and try again.